# css positioning BY center

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have parent box with alot of draggable children with known x,y coordinates.
The problem is to position a child **by its center**, instead of top-left corner.
Sizes of child boxen are auto.

Is there a way to achieve that, without javascript position recalculation on every resize of parent and children?

[image]

P.S.
jquery-ui has plugin 'position' that does mostly what is needed, when using like

```
child.position({ my: center, at: left top, of: parent, offset: x y})
```

But the plugin calulates position in pixels, and i'd prefer to have % so that parent resizing would not involve repositioning all children.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dead Centre.

### CSS:

```
#horizon        
{
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    overflow: visible;
    visibility: visible;
    display: block
}

#content    
{
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-left: -125px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -35px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 250px;
    height: 70px;
    visibility: visible
}
```

**Demo:** http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html

Comment: You positioned content box in horizontal axis manually, using '-125px'.